# Laravel return data in back-end but not in frontend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have `orders` table and I saved my order data in `product_name` column as json, I can get my order data in admin panel but when i try to use same codes in front end to also show order detail to users it return errors.

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

## backend

```
public function index()
{
  $orders = Order::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
  return view('admin.orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

`admin index`

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
  {{$order->payment_id}}
  {{$order->total_items()}}
@endforeach
```

`admin edit page` (to see how exactly i get details from `product_name` column)

```
public function edit($id, Request $request)
{
  $order = Order::find($id);
  $statuses = Orderstatus::all();
  $addresses = Address::where('user_id', $order->user_id)->get();
  return view('admin.orders.edit', compact('order', 'statuses', 'addresses', 'json'));
}
```

`edit blade`

```
<p>#{{$order->payment_id}}</p>
@foreach($order->product_name as $data)
  {{ $data['name'] }}
  {{$data['quantity']}}
  {{number_format($order->total_price(), 0)}}
@endforeach
```

## Frontend

```
public function orders(Request $request)
{
    $orders = Order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('front.orders', compact('orders'));
}
```

`in blade`

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
  #{{$order->ordernu}}
  @foreach($order->product_name as $data)
    <li>{{ $data['name']}}</li>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Then I get this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

any idea on that?

## UPDATE

`dd($orders)` result

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#700 ▼
  #total: 2
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#682 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => Order {#689 ▼
        #fillable: array:10 [▶]
        #casts: array:1 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:16 [▼
          "id" => 15
          "ordernu" => "4173870116"
          "user_id" => 1
          "orderstatus_id" => 7
          "address_id" => 1
          "payment_id" => null
          "product_name" => ""[{\"id\":37,\"name\":\"test product\",\"price\":100000,\"quantity\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Gray\",\"price\":\"7000.00\"}}],\"conditions\":[]} ▶"
          "quantity" => null
          "price" => null
          "note" => "hello this is for test"
          "address" => null
          "phone" => "xxxxxxx"
          "buyer_name" => "xxxxxx"
          "buyer_email" => "admin@admin.com"
          "created_at" => "2018-01-22 10:38:53"
          "updated_at" => "2018-01-22 10:38:53"
        ]
        #original: array:16 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: []
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
      1 => Order {#691 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 5
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://domail.dev/orders"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Comment: dd($orders) in front controller, what's the result?

Comment: Seems `$order->product_name` is json...

Comment: @MahdiYounesi updated

Comment: @MilanChheda yes is json i mentioned in my question.

Comment: So you will need to decode it using `json_decode` before using it in `foreach`

Comment: @MilanChheda i am `protected $casts = [
      'product_name' => 'array',
  ];` as i said it working on backend.

Comment: @mafortis why you saving json data in product_name column why you not save product_id in orders table after that use belongsTo relationship with products table. Always use normalization

Comment: @mafortis improve your database structure else you will face too many issues in future

Comment: @kunal because i need all data of order in one column and this is not cart table to use `product_id` this data come from cart and if you see my `dd` result is included nested info from product itself till user chosen attributes etc. this is main info of order cannot be done with single product id. thanks for advice.

Comment: @MilanChheda I used your way and it works however is still strange to me because i'm using casts normally i shouldn't need to use decode anymore! but here is my issue now. currently i can get total price by times quantity in price of product, but as u see in my `dd` i have attributes which have price also, how can i count that in my total price as well?

Comment: Might be chance like your all object didn't have value "product_name" you can set isset condition and can try again

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired result you  need to loop over `orders.items`, because it's a paginator object

```
foreach($orders.items as $order)
{
  //rest of code
}
```

Comment: 1- doesn't have any connection with pagination `I've tried your way already`. 2- you cannot loop what is looped! `i am in item currently` what more i want to loop?

Comment: you should use `->` instead of `.` though.